# Does Warhammer 40k actually take place in the past?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Just looking at the medieval theme of the universe makes me wonder if this setting takes place 40k years in the past instead of the future. Maybe a story about a pre-flood civilization? What do guys think? I know it's a ridiculous question, but I find the thought fascinating.

Answer (score 10):

Clearly not. The catchphrase of the Warhammer 40'000 game is (emphasis by me):

> In the grim darkness *of the far future*, there is only war.

[Link](https://www.games-workshop.com/de-AT/Vedros?_requestid=3177176) to a site where the quote is used.

You also have a whole timeline for the Warhammer 40k universe, starting with the present (and having known events in our timeline) reaching to the 30th millenium (Horus Heresy) and then to the 40th / 41st.

[Link to the timeline](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Timeline) of Warhammer 40k.

And in 945.M2 (or more commonly known in our way of writing: 1945):

> The Cabal recruits Damon Prytanis during the Battle of Iwo Jima.
>
> From the Lexicanum [article on M2](https://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/M2) in the Warhammer 40k universe

Therefore, the universe is clearly in the future of the human history.